# Using Jest I get: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am using Angular 7 and Jest. When I was running jest with `--codecoverage`, all my tests passed but many branches in the constructor were not covered
(similar to: [Branches on constructor not covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215856/branches-on-constructor-not-covered)).

I spent quite a lot of time checking everywhere how to solve it and it seemed I had to upgrade `jest-preset-angular` to version 7. After I did it, all my test suites fail to run with the following message:

```
src/app/whatever.component.spec.ts
 ● Test suite failed to run
    
 TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'.
```

I've been looking around and I tried to apply the solutions I found (such as [Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047193/cannot-find-type-definition-file-for-jasmine), [ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709410/error-in-error-ts2688-cannot-find-type-definition-file-for-jest), ...) but none worked.

I copy here some of the dependencies I have in package.json:

```
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest-junit": "^6.3.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^7.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
```

My previous version was:

```
    "jest-preset-angular": "^6.0.2",
```

**Update:** I started my project with Angular 6 and Jasmine and I updated it to Angular 7 and Jest. I don't know if this is an important information.

Comment: what version of `ts-jest` do you have? I see an old issue here: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/766

Comment: I have `"ts-jest": "~23.1.3"`. I see the issue you comment is fixed after 23.10.2. I don't know I don't have it updated: it is not in my package.json... I'll try to do it now. Thank you!

Comment: Now I have `"ts-jest: "^24.0.2"` and I still have the same problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Any minimal repo which can be tried?

Comment: How can I run jest in stackblitz? I looked for it but I didn't know how to do it :-(

Comment: If you have "jasmine" in types array of tsconfig.spec.json? It might be the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to tsconfig.spec.json in the types field under the compilerOptions and remove jasmine and add jest

```
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "commonjs",
"outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
"types": ["jest", "node"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved my problem. The solution is based on @Emmy Omega’s answer (that’s why I give him the bounty) and @Akshay Rana’s comment, but had to do some more things. I had `jasmine` indeed in my `tsconfig.spec.json` file, but changing it with `json` (I had already tried it) didn’t fix the problem. To make it work I followed the following steps:

• [Update npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm) (I had an old version and I had some problems installing packages).

• [Remove all Karma related stuff](https://codeburst.io/angular-6-ng-test-with-jest-in-3-minutes-b1fe5ed3417c) that was still there:

`npm remove karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter karma-jasmine karma-jasmine-html-reporter`

• I still had [this](https://git.mylab.th-luebeck.de/oncampus/patterns-and-frameworks/blob/9577511bdcd894884453e46467df9147f4bf3bbe/ui/angular-shop/src/test.ts) `test.ts` file around and I deleted it (I don’t know where it came from). I also remove it from `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`.

• In `tsconfig.spec.json` I changed one occurrence of `jasmine` with `jest` (as suggested).

• Updated `package.json` with `"jest-preset-angular": "^7.0.1`

• Delete all packages in `node_modules` folder and reinstall them all again with `npm i`.

I don’t know exactly which of these steps made the difference but it finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the following error when trying to run Jest in my Angular project.

> TypeScript diagnostics (customize using
>   `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option): error TS2688:
>   Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'. error TS2688: Cannot
>   find type definition file for 'jsdom'.

For me I had to add the type definition packages.

```
yarn add @types/jquery @types/jsdom --dev
```

After that these errors stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but as suggested I changed `jasmine`with `jest` of `tsconfig.spec.json`

then i changed `target` under same file from `es5` to `es2018` and bam