# jest (Angular): change value of spyon().mockReturnValue

Tags: angular, jestjs

In two different tests I want to mock two different values of a function in a given service. I use:

```
    service = TestBed.get(someService);
    spyObj = jest.spyOn(service, 'someFunction').mockReturnValue(of('foo'));
```

and the first test runs well. Then if I write either

```
    spyObj.mockReturnValue(of('second foo'));
```

or

```
    spyObj = jest.spyOn(someService, 'someMethod').mockReturnValue(of('foo'));
```

in the second test, the value I get is still 'foo'. I tried also `mockClear`, `mockReset` and `mockRestore` and none of them seems to do anything at all. I always get 'foo'.

**What should I do to get a different value in my second test?**

I have the following versions of `jest`:

```
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest-junit": "^6.3.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^6.0.2",
```

I can't update `jest-preset-angular` because I have [this non-solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810980/using-jest-i-get-cannot-find-type-definition-file-for-jasmine). :-(

Here the code a bit more expanded:

```
describe('whatever', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;
  let someService: SomeService;
  let spyObj: jest.Mock<Observable<any>, [string | string[], object?]>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SomeModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
      providers: [ SomeService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    someService = TestBed.get(SomeService);
    spyObj = jest.spyOn(someService, 'someMethod').mockReturnValue(of('foo'));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check someFunction when someService returns "foo"', () => {
    component.someFunction(); // This function uses the value of someService
    // Debugging inside someFunction I get "foo"
    expect(component.something).toEqual('foo');
  });

  it('should check someFunction when someService returns "second foo"', () => {
    spyObj.mockReturnValue(of('second foo'));

// this does not work either:
//    spyObj = jest.spyOn(someService, 'someMethod').mockReturnValue(of('second foo'));

    component.someFunction(); // This function uses the value of someService
    // Debugging inside someFunction I still get "foo"
    expect(component.something).toEqual('second foo');
  });
});
```

Comment: Try calling `jest.restoreAllMocks()` in the `afterEach` hook. Also, I don't if this might help https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values

Comment: It didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you create your component in a separate function with an argument which will be used inside `mockReturnValue`, then the solution works. However I don't accept this answer because I still don't understand why `mockReturnValue` can't be overwritten as expected and I hope somebody can still clarify it.

Here the code that works:

```
describe('whatever', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;
  let someService: SomeService;
  let spyObj: jest.Mock<Observable<any>, [string | string[], object?]>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SomeModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
      providers: [ SomeService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    customBeforeEach();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check someFunction when someService returns "foo"', () => {
    customBeforeEach();
    component.someFunction();
    expect(component.something).toEqual('foo');
  });

  it('should check someFunction when someService returns "second foo"', () => {
    customBeforeEach('second foo');
    component.someFunction(); 
    expect(component.something).toEqual('second foo');
  });

  function customBeforeEach(value = 'foo'): void {
    someService = TestBed.get(SomeService);
    spyObj = jest.spyOn(someService, 'someMethod').mockReturnValue(of(value));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }
});
```